# Building React Navigation v5 stack with Stack Navigation and Tab Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently attempting to get my head round how to build out my React Navigation stack with v5, and not using a switchNavigator.

My basic app structure is such (will post an image of a flow below):

```
check Auth    
    -> signed in yes
      -> tab navigation (with stack navigators nested within)    
    -> signed in no
      -> nested stack navigator
```

But I just can't figure out how I should build the root of my app. I don't know how to combine my tab navigator and stack navigator together to make my app function from start to finish.

(It's worth noting, the 'check Auth' is an actual screen, not a conditional)

Here's my illustration showing my project layout:

[image]

Can someone advise please how I can build this out? Any tips or general structure / advice on how best to do it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Is the sole purpose of your 'check auth' screen to determine whether or not your user is currently signed in?

Comment: I'm also planning on using that screen for Face ID / Touch ID and also doing the API calls within my Context to get the necessary user data ahead of accessing their dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

So what I've typically done in the past is the render either or, not both. So as an example, the root navigation could look as follows:

```
import { NavigationContainer as RootNavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";


const Navigation = () => {
  const { someToken } = useContext(SomeContext);

  return (
    <RootNavigationContainer>
      {!someToken ? <AuthStack /> : <MainStack />}
    </RootNavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The determining of the user's authenticated state should be done while the Splash Screen is being shown, using a separate component just confuses the flow IMO. If the user is authenticated, you can set some state (in the example a token is set on the context) which will then drive which navigation stack is shown.

In my example, `AuthStack` would contain all of the screens where you user is unauthenticated - so your login, registration etc. `MainStack` would contain the screens that should only be shown to authenticated users.

Things like FaceID should be included in your Login flow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I get it better - but what do you mean by 'splash screen'?

Comment: So you can either show a Splash Screen (that you would have to create yourself) that acts as a buffer for the user while you collect data before your user sees anything meaningful, or use (assuming you are using expo) something like AppLoading: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/