# Reach root stack from nested stack

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack

How can I reach the login screen under AuthStack.Navigator from a nested screen stack. Below is the structure of the app.

[App Navigation Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVLQx.png)

Comment: Are you asking how you would go about navigating to the login screen from one of those stacks? Also please let us know which version of react-navigation you are using.

Comment: react navigation 5. i wanted to logout from Settings Screen and go back to Login Screen but it seems impossible to do since the the Settings Screen is in a different navigator with the Login Screen

Comment: I don't think you need to manage so many navigators, you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330085/3832047 for some advice I gave a while ago. Typically you only need a navigation for 'authenticated' and one for 'unauthenticated' states.